# Que es mejor o mas eficiente para obtener datos desde sql, a través de Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecutQuery o SqlClient.SqlDataReader?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, vb.net, linq-to-sql

Comparto código en el que muestro como estoy utilizando ambos métodos, para que les sea mas fácil hacerme una recomendación de cual usar y porque?

Metodo Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecutQuery

Public Function ObtenerProducto(ByVal Id As String, ByVal Almacen As String) As List(Of venta.Productos)

```
    Dim Datos As List(Of venta.Producto) = New List(Of enta.Producto)
    Dim Consulta As String
    Try

        Consulta = "SELECT 
                           Id,
                            Nombre,
                            Descripcion,
                    FROM   
                           DBO.Productos
                    WHERE
                        Id = {0}
                        AND Almacen = {1} "
        '  Dim db As New venta(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbventa").ToString())
        ' Inherits DataContext
        'Public Sub New(ByVal Conexion As String)
        '   MyBase.New(Conexion)
        'End Sub

        Datos = db.ExecuteQuery(Of venta.Productos)(Consulta, Id, Almacen).ToList()

    Catch ex As Exception
        NotificarError(ex)

    End Try

    Return Datos

End Function
```

Metodo usando SqlClient.SqlDataReader

Public Function ObtenerProducto(ByVal Id As String, ByVal Almacen As String) As List(Of venta.Producto)

```
Dim Datos As List(Of venta.Producto) = New List(Of venta.Producto)
Dim Consulta As String
Try

    Consulta = "SELECT 
                       Id,
                        Nombre,
                        Descripcion
                FROM   
                       DBO.Productos
                WHERE
                    Id = @Id
                    AND Almacen = @Almacen "
    Dim SqlConexion As Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbventa").ToString())

    Dim SqlComando As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(Consulta, SqlConexion)
    Dim Sqldr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader

    SqlComando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Id
    SqlComando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Almacen", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Almacen

    Dim previousConnectionState As Global.System.Data.ConnectionState = SqlComando.Connection.State
    If ((SqlComando.Connection.State And Global.System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) <> Global.System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) Then
        SqlConexion.Open()
    End If


    Sqldr = SqlComando.ExecuteReader()

    While Sqldr.Read()
        Dim valor As venta.pruducto = New venta.pruducto

        valor.Id = Sqldr(0).ToString()
        valor.Nombre = Sqldr(1).ToString()
        valor.Descripcion = Sqldr(2).ToString()

        Datos.add(valor)
    End While

    Sqldr.Close()

    If (previousConnectionState = Global.System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) Then
        SqlConexion.Close()
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    NotificarError(ex)
End Try

Return Datos
```

End Function

> El objetivo de esta consulta es utilizar un método para el desarrollo de web API.

> Gracias por su colaboración.

Comment: No sé si tu consulta puede ser considerada como una pregunta basada en opiniones.

Comment: Hola @Elrod4, cuando se trata de obtener un mejor rendimiento no hay una respuesta única porque depende de muchos factores. Lo que te puedo recomendar, ya que tienes los dos métodos escritos, es que hagas las pruebas con tu escenario y conjunto de datos particular. En lo personal, yo prefiero utilizar SqlDataReader.

Comment: Exactamente sobre eso va la consulta, la idea es utilizar el método mas eficiente, en el mundo real, donde hay un gran numero de usuarios conectados a los servicios y ademas otros procesos analizando los datos. En este sentido me preocupan las conexiones simultaneas y que en algún momento no se pueda ejecutar el proceso porque la conexión esta abierta o casos por el estilo. también lo de la seguridad, en el caso de linq la forma en la que le paso los parámetros. Quisiera una comparativa de como maneja cada método este tipo situaciones.